# pass 2 parameters and use "like" in SQL Server 2005 Stored procedure

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql, stored-procedures

I want to pass 2 parameters to SQL stored procedure and use "like" statement as so:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.StoredProcedure1
    @project varchar(max)
    @group varchar(50)
AS
BEGIN 
    SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE Projectname = @project and Resource_ID like '%' + @group + '%'
END
```

It says that there is incorrect syntax near @group and that I must declare scalar variable @project.

Any idea how can I make this work?

Thanks!

Greg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your parameter list has a missing comma

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.StoredProcedure1
    @project varchar(max), --missing comma
    @group varchar(50)
AS
...
```

Comment: Thanks! Thats some silly mistake..too bad the compiler couldnt tell me that :(